# $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-a m^2}}{m^2}}$ as an Integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

I have a series that I want to find an integral that can replace integral with this series in my calculation.

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-a m^2}}{m^2}}$$

which integral is equal with my series?

thanks

Comment: I removed the tag precalculus as it doesnt appy here.

Answer (score 2):

Consider :
$$f(a):=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-a\,m^2}}{m^2}}$$
then

$$f'(a)=-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}e^{-a\,m^2}=\frac 12\left(1-\theta_3\left(0,e^{-a}\right)\right)$$

with $\theta_3$ a [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

So that you got the integral of a theta function...