# What is the name of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, zeta-functions

I am a physicist, and working on some project I have found this series:

$$
S(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-tn^2}}{n^2}
$$

so that $S(0) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, the classic Euler problem.

Sadly, this series does not admit an easy solution using the complex integral trick for general $t$, for example. But I am sure someone must have found a name for this, or is just one case of some generalized zeta function (or maybe a Jacobi function?).

I am digging through Wikipedia, but I haven't been able to find anything exactly like this yet. Does anyone know how to express it in terms of other known functions?

Comment: See the excellent answer of Raymond Manzoni [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/323126)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I found it using approach0.xyz mathematics [search engine ; example :https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5ET%20%5Cexp(tA)dt%24%2C%20matrix%20expansion&p=2]

Comment: @JeanMarie. You can be sure that any answer coming from Raymond is pure beauty ! The one you mention is just fantastic. Cheers and take care. :-)

Comment: @JeanMarie I was not aware of that website, thank you! I knew it was probably a common question, I just didn't know how to search for it. That website just solves that!

Comment: @Claude Leibovici That's right ! Very happy you have escaped the worse. As you say, we must still be very cautious !